# Conjugate of elements in the Dihedral Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

I was trying to do the following from a past exam of my Rings and Groups' professor

> Classify all conjugacy classes of the elements in the dihedral group $D_n$ = $\{ 1,r,r^2, ... , r^{n-1} ,s ,rs ,r^2s , ... ,r^{n-1} \}$ = $\mathopen{<} r,s \ | \ r^n=1; s^2=1, (rs)^2=1   \mathopen{>}$

A brief reminder that $D_n$ can be understood from a geometrical point of view, $D_n$ is the group of "symmetries" of a regular $n$-gon.

Given two elements $x,a$ in a group G, we define the **conjugate of $a$ through $x$** **as** the element $x^{-1}ax$

We define the **conjugacy class** of an element $a$ in a **group G** as $[a]=\{ x^{-1}ax  \ | \ x \in G  \}$

More specifically, I'm trying to calculate the following :

1. The conjugate of a rotation $r^k$ through a rotation $r^j$ and through a symmetry $r^js$.
2. Determine the conjugacy class of $r^k$ in $D_n$. How many elements does it have?
3. The conjugate of a symmetry $s$ through a rotation $r^j$ and through a symmetry $r^js$.
4. Determine the conjugacy class of $s$ in $D_n$. How many elements does it have?

---

1. Evidently through $r^j$ we have, $r^{-j}r^kr^j = r^{-j+k+j}=r^k$.

   Now through $r^js$ we get, $(r^js)^{-1}r^k(r^js) = s^{-1}r^{-j}r^kr^js = s^{-1}r^ks$.

I don't know how to classify this last one, and the ones from 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be sufficient to solve this to know that
$$s^{-1}=s$$
which you can see from $s^2=1$, so $s^2s^{-1}=s^{-1}$, and since
$$rsrs = 1$$
we have
$$srs = r^{-1}$$
so
$$sr = r^{-1}s$$
I'm not going to answer all of the questions, but this should be enough to do it yourself.

Comment: Could you please explain why those equalities are true?

Comment: @M.Navarro Edited, take a look.

Comment: Obviously, thank you so much. I’ll update my answer when I make some progress. Otherwise I’ll come back to ask for help